# fillna by avoiding row wise operation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a data frame in which there is a column containing several NaN values. The dataframe looks like this:

```
            col_1   col_2
2022-10-31  99.094  102.498
2022-11-30  99.001  101.880
2022-12-31     NaN  108.498
2023-01-31     NaN  100.500
```

I want to fill those NaN based on the simple calculation below:
desired_val = (previous value in col_1 * current value in col_2) / previous value in col_2

which means,

df.loc['2022-12-31', 'col_1'] should be = (99.001 * 108.498) / 101.880 = 105.432

and df.loc['2023-01-31', 'col_1'] should be = (105.432 * 100.500) / 108.498 = 97.660

I found solution by using row by row operation but it is slow when the dataset is big. I tried column wise operation by using this:

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].fillna(
        (df[col_1].shift(1) * df[col_2])
        / df[col_2].shift(1)
       )
```

But it does work only for one row and then it does not go further. Is there any column wise pandas solution for that?

Comment: Note that if you repeat your code in a loop this works, it's just that the previous col_1 value is not yet calculated, thus my use of `ffill` in my answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of your operation and see that you multiply by `x` in one row and divide by `x` in the next row.

Thus you can simplify the result to:

```
col1_value = (last_valid_col1_value * current_col2_value)
             / col2_value_at_last_valid_col1_position
```

Which can be translated as:

```
# is the row a NA?
m1 = df['col_1'].isna()
# is the next row a NA?
m2 = df['col_1'].shift(-1).isna()

df.loc[m1, 'col_1'] = (df['col_1'].div(df['col_2'])
                       .where(m2 & ~m1).ffill()
                       .mul(df['col_2'])[m1]
                      )
```

Output:

```
                 col_1    col_2
2022-10-31   99.094000  102.498
2022-11-30   99.001000  101.880
2022-12-31  105.431984  108.498
2023-01-31   97.659997  100.500
```

Intermediates:

```
             col_1    col_2     m1     m2  m2&~m1  ffilled(col1/col2)      result
2022-10-31  99.094  102.498  False  False   False                 NaN         NaN
2022-11-30  99.001  101.880  False   True    True            0.971741         NaN
2022-12-31     NaN  108.498   True   True   False            0.971741  105.431984
2023-01-31     NaN  100.500   True   True   False            0.971741   97.659997
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which uses a mathematical formula (under the assumption that `col_1` is *only* `NaN` after the first `NaN`):

```
col1_NaN = last_not_NaN_of_col1 * 
           cumprod(col2_after_last_not_NaN_col1/col2.shift)
```

---

```
df.assign(col_1 = df['col_1'].combine_first(
    df['col_1'][df['col_1'].last_valid_index()] * 
    df['col_2'].div(df['col_2'].shift())[df['col_1'].isna()].cumprod()))
```

---

Output:

```
                 col_1    col_2
2022-10-31   99.094000  102.498
2022-11-30   99.001000  101.880
2022-12-31  105.431984  108.498
2023-01-31   97.659997  100.500
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two different suggestions. Because of the risk of two or more NaN values following each other in column_1 you can not do a simple vectorized approach.

Solution 1 will simply iterate and solve it one row at a time.
Solution 2 will perform a vectorized approach but only to the subset of values that will allow it (so to missing values in columnd_1 that have non-missing values above it), and then repeat until all values are filled.

I am not sure which will be faster for your dataset. (I have assumed that column_2 has no missing values).

Solution 1:

```
# Iterate over each row
for i in df.index:
    # check if value in col_1 is NaN
    if pd.isnull(df.loc[i, 'col_1']):
        df.loc[i, 'col_1'] = (df.loc[i-1, 'col_1'] * df.loc[i, 'col_2']) / df.loc[i-1, 'col_2']
```

Solution 2:

```py
while df['col_1'].isnull().any():
    # Identify rows where col_1 is NaN and the previous row in col_1 is not NaN
    mask = df['col_1'].isnull() & df['col_1'].shift().notna()
    
    # Apply the formula only on those rows
    df.loc[mask, 'col_1'] = (df.loc[mask, 'col_1'].shift() * df.loc[mask, 'col_2']) / df.loc[mask, 'col_2'].shift()
```

Solution 2 identifies all rows where `col_1` is NaN and the previous row in `col_1` is not NaN. The formula is then applied only to those rows. This process is repeated until all NaN values in `col_1` are filled.

With a 50000 row set of synthetically generated data similar to yours, with approx. 10000 NaN values, including some double and some triple NaN values following each other in column_1, but no NaN values in column_2, Solution 1 executed in 2s 60ms and Solution 2 executed in 1s 388ms. I also tried both solutions for data with less and with more NaN values. Both performed slower and faster respecitvely and the speed difference was approx the same, with Solution 2 always being faster.

Code for generating similar data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)

# Create date range
dates = pd.date_range('2022-10-31', periods=50000)

# Create random data for col_2
col_2 = np.random.uniform(100, 110, 50000)

# Create data for col_1, with NaN at specific intervals
col_1 = np.where((np.arange(50000) % 10) == 0, np.nan, np.random.uniform(90, 100, 50000))

# Adding consecutive NaNs at different intervals
for i in range(len(col_1)):
    if i % 15 == 0:
        if i+1 < len(col_1):  # Making sure we don't go out of bounds
            col_1[i+1] = np.nan
    if i % 40 == 0:
        if i+2 < len(col_1):  # Making sure we don't go out of bounds
            col_1[i+2] = np.nan
    if i % 60 == 0:
        if i+3 < len(col_1):  # Making sure we don't go out of bounds
            col_1[i+3] = np.nan
    if i % 120 == 0:
        if i+4 < len(col_1):  # Making sure we don't go out of bounds
            col_1[i+4] = np.nan

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': col_1, 'col_2': col_2}, index=dates)

# Making sure the first value is not NaN
df.loc[dates[0], 'col_1'] = 99.094

print(df.head(20))

# Count NaNs in col_1
num_nan = df['col_1'].isnull().sum()
print(f"The number of NaN values in col_1 is {num_nan}")
```

This generates some sections that have up to 5 NaN values following each other, and still Solution 2 was faster (Solution 1: 2s 460ms, Solution 2: 1s 621ms)

Comment: I tried mozway's code on the 50000 and it executes in around 10ms so definitely the better option.

Comment: As I mentioned, row wise solution is done but I discarded due to lower speed. Both of these either going row by row or running a for loop which reduces the benefit of using pandas.

Comment: Yes, but to get to the solution that mozway did, you need huge brains and huge experience and I clearly lack at least one of those.

Comment: After thinking about the logic in mozways code, I believe the forward fill will give same value to use also to all the next NaN for the calculation so if there are more than two NaN in a row in your data, you will not get the correct values in any row that has two or more NaN above it. Please correct me if I am wrong.